# How can I combine light and fan switches into a single switch?

Tags: electrical, switch

How do I convert two independent switches to a single switch? My plan is to remove two switches in bathroom ( light and fan) with one Lutron occupancy switch.

[image: current setup]

I have attached little simpler version of switches. There is no jumper wire when I took the black wire off of second switch. While it's loop around and going to wire nut. Same is case with first switch. From top it looks like there are 2 black wire attached to each switch but that's not the case. They are looped around and going to wire nut.

[image]

Is single red wire on top of first switch and single black wire on top of second switch, represents load? Are you suggesting to jump those two together and connect it to switch one with help of jump wire and write nut?
Can you draw little pic for dummies?

Comment: See the solitary black wire on the left switch?  Mark that with blue tape. Then, all the wires in this box will be meaningfully color-coded!

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one.

With the power off, take the black wire off the 2nd switch that connects the 2 switches and remove the jumper and wire nut.  These will be used to make a pig tail.

Connect the single red with the single black and the short wire removed from the 2nd switch using the wire nut.

Connect the pig tail to the first switch. Now you have 2 wires connected to the switch going to the loads and the hot supply from the outlet on the other side.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I will try and report back soon.

Comment: Hi Ed, I added current wiring picture. It was little confusing so I didn't convert 2 to 1. Let me know if you need any additional details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your diagram (which is not the same as your picture, btw), you have one of the two following conditions:

```
?? -> switch -> wire nut -> switch -> outlet
```

or:

```
outlet -> switch -> wire nut -> switch -> ??
```

Clearly, power to both switches comes from the same circuit.

To replace two switches with one, simply eliminate one switch from the "power" circuit, and connect both outgoing wires (one is red, one is black in your photo) to the same switch.

Beware: some switches are "3-way", and so while they may appear to have separate terminals, the reality is they don't. You'll need to connect both leads to the *same* terminal. (For simple switches, there are only two terminals, one for power in, one for power out. Obviously, you'll also have to connect both outgoing leads to the same terminal in this case, too.)